# Using List of HashMap<String, dynamic> to populate ListView Builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I am having a `json` response that looks like this below

```
[
  {
        "email": "kamchatka@mail.com",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "name": "kamchatka",
        "picture": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/fashion-beauty-african-american-beautiful-woman-profile-portrait-picture-id1197851431?k=20&m=1197851431&s=612x612&w=0&h=g3tb57yHvOHiFT3F35STNKNCQB0W1e9vKqFocnvnehE=",
        "index": 1,
        "imageFetchType": "networkImage"
  },
  {
        "email": "valjakutse@mail.com",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "name": "Valjakutse",
        "picture": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561406636-b80293969660?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8YmxhY2slMjBsYWR5fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80",
        "index": 2,
        "imageFetchType": "imageNetwork"
  }
  
]
```

Want i want to achieve is populating a **ListView Builder** without using a `class` but instead using a `List` of `HashMap<String, dynamic>`

Below is how i am mapping the string response into `List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>` using `async` **Future**

```
Future<List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>>
  _fetchUsersUsingListOfStringDynamicHashMap() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/Eh5AlPjYVv6C/data"),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer tltsp6dmnbif01jy9xfo9ssn4620u89xhuwcm5t3",
          });

      final List<HashMap<String, dynamic>> responseList;

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        responseList = json
            .decode(response.body)
            .map<HashMap<String, dynamic>>(
                (e) => HashMap<String, dynamic>.from(e))
            .toList();
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        responseList = [];
      } else {
        responseList = [];
      }

      return responseList;
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        Logger().wtf("FetchUsersUsingListOfStringObjectHashMapException $e");
      }

      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

And below is my **FutureBuilder** inside a **SizedBox**

```
SizedBox(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _fetchUsersUsingListOfStringDynamicHashMap(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot) {
              if (asyncSnapshot.data == null) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                return RefreshIndicator(
                  // background color
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    // refresh circular progress indicator color
                    color: Colors.green,
                    onRefresh: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        _fetchUsersUsingListOfStringDynamicHashMap();
                      });
                    },
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          title: Text(asyncSnapshot.data[index]."email" ?? ''),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              asyncSnapshot.data[index]."name" ?? ''),
                        );
                      },
                    ));
              }
            }),
      ),
```

I am stuck in certain piece of code below where there is a **ListView.Builder** i am getting an `Expected an identifier.` error

```
return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          title: Text(asyncSnapshot.data[index]."email" ?? ''),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              asyncSnapshot.data[index]."name" ?? ''),
                        );
```

I have tried the following below

```
return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          title: Text(asyncSnapshot.data["email"] ?? ''),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              asyncSnapshot.data["name"] ?? ''),
                        );
```

But i am getting the error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of index'` how can i be able to use the keys from the hashmap to set title as email and subtitle as name when i am using ListTile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 asyncSnapshot.data[index]["name"]
```

And

```
 asyncSnapshot.data[index]["email"]
```

Comment: Please accept it if it answers your question.